# The results of regular expressions in Java exceeded my expectations

Tags: java, regex

I've tried many methods and looked up the Pattern&&Matcher method in the jdk1.7 manual, but the results have not changed. I don't know what's wrong, please help me to get the correct result! thanks!

[image: (Click me! im image!!!) hopeful]

[image: (Click me! im image!!!) unhopeful]

***Project at here...***

*testRegex.java:*

```
package testRegex;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

public class testRegex {
    public String callSendHttpGet(String url) {
        return sendHttpGet(url);
    }
    private static String sendHttpGet(String url) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            URL realUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = realUrl.openConnection();
            conn.connect();

            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(result + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occurs when a GET request is sent." + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> callRegex2String(String line,
            String regex) {
        return regex2String(line, regex);
    }
    private static ArrayList<String> regex2String(String line,
            String regex) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

            if (m.find()) {
                for (int i=0; i<m.groupCount(); i++) {
                    list.add(m.group(i));
                }
                return list;
            }
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list.clear(); list.add("Nothing!");
        return list;
    }
}
```

*myapp.java:*

```
package testRegex;

import java.util.List;

public class myapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testRegex app = new testRegex();
        String url = "https://www.baidu.com";

        String result = app.callSendHttpGet(url);
        List<String> getResult = app.callRegex2String(result,
                "src\\s*=\\s*(.*?)(\"|>|\\s)");
//      for (int i=0; i<getResult.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(getResult);
//      }
    }
}
```

Line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--STATUS OK--><html> <head><meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=Edge><meta content=always name=referrer><link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=https://ss1.bdstatic.com/5eN1bjq8AAUYm2zgoY3K/r/www/cache/bdorz/baidu.min.css><title>百度一下，你就知道</title></head> <body link=#0000cc> <div id=wrapper> <div id=head> <div class=head_wrapper> <div class=s_form> <div class=s_form_wrapper> <div id=lg> <img hidefocus=true src=//www.baidu.com/img/bd_logo1.png width=270 height=129> </div> <form id=form name=f action=//www.baidu.com/s class=fm> <input type=hidden name=bdorz_come value=1> <input type=hidden name=ie value=utf-8> <input type=hidden name=f value=8> <input type=hidden name=rsv_bp value=1> <input type=hidden name=rsv_idx value=1> <input type=hidden name=tn value=baidu><span class="bg s_ipt_wr"><input id=kw name=wd class=s_ipt value maxlength=255 autocomplete=off autofocus=autofocus></span><span class="bg s_btn_wr"><input type=submit id=su value=百度一下 class="bg s_btn" autofocus></span> </form> </div> </div> <div id=u1> <a href=http://news.baidu.com name=tj_trnews class=mnav>新闻</a> <a href=https://www.hao123.com name=tj_trhao123 class=mnav>hao123</a> <a href=http://map.baidu.com name=tj_trmap class=mnav>地图</a> <a href=http://v.baidu.com name=tj_trvideo class=mnav>视频</a> <a href=http://tieba.baidu.com name=tj_trtieba class=mnav>贴吧</a> <noscript> <a href=http://www.baidu.com/bdorz/login.gif?login&amp;tpl=mn&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.baidu.com%2f%3fbdorz_come%3d1 name=tj_login class=lb>登录</a> </noscript> <script>document.write('<a href="http://www.baidu.com/bdorz/login.gif?login&tpl=mn&u='+ encodeURIComponent(window.location.href+ (window.location.search === "" ? "?" : "&")+ "bdorz_come=1")+ '" name="tj_login" class="lb">登录</a>');                </script> <a href=//www.baidu.com/more/ name=tj_briicon class=bri style="display: block;">更多产品</a> </div> </div> </div> <div id=ftCon> <div id=ftConw> <p id=lh> <a href=http://home.baidu.com>关于百度</a> <a href=http://ir.baidu.com>About Baidu</a> </p> <p id=cp>&copy;2017&nbsp;Baidu&nbsp;<a href=http://www.baidu.com/duty/>使用百度前必读</a>&nbsp; <a href=http://jianyi.baidu.com/ class=cp-feedback>意见反馈</a>&nbsp;京ICP证030173号&nbsp; <img src=//www.baidu.com/img/gs.gif> </p> </div> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

regex:

```
src\s*=\s*(.*?)("|>|\s)
```

Comment: Please use an actual HTML parser, not regex... https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2308683

Comment: Is it still allowed to link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9455968?